# Secure chat -- is CTCP a good option?

Tags: network

Not sure if this is the proper forum for my question, but I've recently read over at [Encrypt Everything](https://www.encrypteverything.ca/index.php?title=IRC_Anonymity_Guide) that CTCP is a poor choice if you want to keep your chats secure. I'm beginning at security, so I'm not sure on why DCC would fall behind IRC (fewer possible leaks when direct contact is required, no?) but if this is true, are there more secure options out there? What are the benefits/drawbacks of these options? Is a more secure DCC chat possible?

I'm already using OTR, not routing over Tor currently though.

Comment: Check out http://silcnet.org/

Comment: I think you are confused: CTCP is just PRIVMSG with a special control character (`^A`) surrounding the entirety of the message. You mean DCC, which is initiated using a CTCP message, but then continues on a Direct Client Connection. There's also the problem that DCC is IPv4-only (the initiation message sends the IP address as decimal 32-bit unsigned number), and that usually the parties are firewalled, and that DCC is normally unencrypted.

Answer (score 1):

For instance, CTCP does not support SSL, where IRC does. However, with standard IRC, there is no mechanism to check whether other parties are using SSL, and whether server links are protected.

The point of that [Encrypt Everything page](https://www.encrypteverything.ca/index.php?title=IRC_Anonymity_Guide) is that CTCP divulges a large amount of information about you and your client. It is not about confidentiality of your communications - that's not available with IRC (plaintext communication) anyway.

With CTCP/DCC, things like your timezone, OS and client version are available. Obviously, timezone is anyway available from your IP address.

Comment: Thanks, but do you have any advice on which chat methods I could use to be more secure?